# Gradle Idea plugin - directory as project library

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I added idea plugin to my gradle build recently, now I want to make `gradle idea` task append 3 rd libraries to generated idea configuration. Now, when I open my project in idea, classes from those libraries are not visible and I have plenty errors. Libraries are in directory, path to directory is `/some/path`.

To achieve this I added to my build.gradle following section :

```
idea {
  project {
    projectLibraries << new ProjectLibrary(name: "my-libs", classes: [new Path("/some/path")])
  }
}
```

But after running `gradle idea` i'm getting following error :

> No signature of method:
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.ProjectLibrary.CLASSES() is
>   applicable for argument types:
>   (org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.ProjectLibrary$_addToNode_closure1_closure2)
>   values:
>   [org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.ProjectLibrary$_addToNode_closure1_closure2@58115f]

I have Gradle 2.0, Groovy 2.3.3

Does anyone have idea, how to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the snippet is similar to one in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaProject.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaProject:projectLibraries There is a bug in this documentation and it will be fixed in next version.

The problem is that the type of `ProjectLibrary.classes` is `Set<File>`. You can use something like `classes: [new File("/some/path")]`